# Execution permission is denied on a stored procedure which is created by me while running a report which uses the same sp

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure, and used it to create a report in report builder. When I run the report, it says that execute permission was denied. But I can execute that stored procedure in the SQL SERVER. I could run the report when I give the same stored procedure as query. Can you please suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In database sp is using your credentials ,but in report  it may be using different credentials,Check under which account SSRS reports are connectiing to DB and see if that account has access

Answer (score 0):

log in to SQL Server and do the following :

```
GRANT EXEC ON [YourStoredProcedure] TO [TheReportServerUser]
```

Make sure the account you are using for this process have the appropriate permissions.